# lightbox contact form in php

Tags: php, forms, lightbox, contacts

I am now to this altogether. I need the success message when the lightbox contact form is posted to appear in the lightbox. The mail is not sent out neither is the success message displayed.

I have the following code in my site to collect the data and post it to a separate page that send out mail. The thing is email is not sent out using the mail.php file. Need help.

```
<script>
        function sendEmail() {
            // 1. Create XHR instance - Start

            var xhr;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }

            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            else {
                throw new Error("Form is not supported by this browser");
            }

            // 1. Create XHR instance - End

            // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                        // document.getElementById('loadix').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                        if(xhr.responseText == "success"){
                            $('#confirmation').html("<h2><i>Thank you for Registering for the webinar. An email with a link to the webinar will be emailed to you soon.</i></h2>");
                            $('#tosend').val(0);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#confirmation').html("<h2>Email sending failed</h2>");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start
            var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var Home_phone = document.getElementById("Home_phone").value;
    var full_name = document.getElementById("full_name").value;
    var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
            var tosend = document.getElementById("tosend").value;

            var post_str = "&message=" + message +"&subject=" + subject +"&email=" + email +"&Home_phone=" + Home_phone +"&full_name=" + full_name +"&day=" + day;

            // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - Start 
            if(tosend == 1){
                xhr.open('POST', 'mail.php');
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xhr.send(post_str);
            }
            // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - End

    return true;
      }
```

The **mail.php** has the following code.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email_to = "xxx@gmail.com"; 
$full_name = $_POST['full_name']; // required 
$day = $_POST['day']; // required 
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$Home_phone = $_POST['Home_phone']; // not required 
$subject = $_POST['subject']; // required
$message = $_POST['message']; // required

$email_message = "Webinar request details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string); 
}
$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";
$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($full_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Home_phone: ".clean_string($Home_phone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "Day: ".clean_string($day)."\n";

// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
 'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will have a look at jQuery for an ajax call. it is a short way to make a complex post request in less then 3 lines of code. with the jqXHR Objects you can handle the response.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

in mail.php you have used the mail function. at the beginning you used the @, that means that the mail function will not throw any error. maybe you have to remove it to see any errors while sending the email.

here an updated mail.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "xxx@gmail.com";
    $full_name = $_POST['full_name']; // required 
    $day = $_POST['day']; // required 
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $Home_phone = $_POST['Home_phone']; // not required 
    $subject = $_POST['subject']; // required
    $message = $_POST['message']; // required

    $email_message = "Webinar request details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Message: " . clean_string($message) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Name: " . clean_string($full_name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Home_phone: " . clean_string($Home_phone) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: " . clean_string($email_from) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Day: " . clean_string($day) . "\n";

    $headers = 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $error = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    if ($error) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' Internal Server Error', true, 500);
    }
} else {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' Bad Request', true, 400);
}
```

please remember that there is no validation for a correct email. you form can be used for sending spam mails